# What are the benefits and drawbacks of using classes that only differ in their constructors?

Tags: c++, oop

I have a class `SpecialArray` which can be accessed in the same way as a standard two-dimensional array; i.e., as `A[i][j]`. It is frequently necessary to extract a one-dimensional array of `int` from this object. The details of the extraction, which depend on other passed parameters, are immaterial; I'm interested in designing the interface of the operation.

What are the benefits and drawbacks of the following approaches to accomplishing this task?

**Option 1**

We define a function:

```
std::vector<int> extract(const SpecialArray &A, ...)
```

where here `...` refers to other parameters that determine the content of the one-dimensional array, and use it as:

```
std::vector<int> output = extract(A,...);
```

**Option 2**

We create a class that inherits from std::vector and constructs itself:

```
class SpecialArrayExtract : public std::vector<int> {
    public:
        SpecialArrayExtract(const SpecialArray &A, ...);
};
```

where the constructor (or, equivalently, an `init` function) uses the `...` input to fill `*this` with the appropriate data, and we use it as:

```
SpecialArrayExtract output(A,...);
```

**Option 3**

We proceed exactly as in Option 2, but do not inherit from `std::vector<int>` and instead have a `private` member `std::vector<int>` with interface exposed as needed:

```
class SpecialArrayExtract {
    private:
        std::vector<int> m_data;
    public:
        SpecialArrayExtract(const SpecialArray &A, ...);
        [Wrapper functions for std::vector<int> here.]
};
```

**Commentary**

The application is high-performance, but with RVO in Option 1, I'm assuming these should all perform equivalently.

Tying this back into the title, the point I'm trying to get at is that both Options 2 and 3 define classes that are essentially just `std::vector<int>` with a different name and a special constructor. when -- if ever! -- is this a reasonable idea, and which is the better way to do it?

Comment: So you have a data structure that holds a number of arrays, and you need to provide access to whole arrays? Your extract method copies from an internally stored array to a destination array (no matter if RVO or move semantics); is it really necessary to copy it?

Comment: Option 2 is very bad, you shouldn't inherit publicly from std::vector, as it has no virtual destructor...

Comment: @DyP The extracted array is a sequence of elements from the original multidimensional array that are not [likely] adjacent in memory. (That is, I'm not simply pulling out a column or row of a matrix here.) I will need to loop over the extracted array repeatedly, and I need those elements to be contiguous in memory for optimal cache use.

Comment: I'd go with option 1 if the extraction can be done via SpecialArray's public interface. I don't see the need for a new class in that case.

Comment: The problem of option 1 is you cannot use a pre-resized/reserved array nor any other pre-allocated storage to receive/store the vector. I'd rather use a version with iterators. If it doesn't have to access private data members, I'd prefer a non-member function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe option one makes the most sense because it:

- has a trivially simple interface
- does not create additional classes
- can be extended via templates for other "extraction" operations

I am against option two because if you inherit from `std::vector<int>` you are saying that the `SpecialArrayExtract` **is-a** `std::vector<int>`, and provide a single operation (the constructor) to create it. If you think about it, it is just a convoluted way to do exactly the same as your first alternative.

Option three seems to be a premature optimization (you are opting for containment instead of inheritance, as if you would be preemptively expecting the underlying data container to change) which convolutes even more than alternative two.

As for the option four (suggested in an answer), I believe that a class interface should keep as few as possible instance methods, and instead offer non-member functions (refer to [this article](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197) to learn the rationale).

If your needs were to change in the future (for example, you decide that another container or data type serves better your needs) you could modify the function via templates. This would give you all the advantages of having a separate class, but not the overhead. And the same operation (with the exact same name) could apply to any possible combination of ContainerTypes (i.e., `std::vector<int>`, or `std::array<int, 12>`, or whatever) and ArrayTypes (`SpecialArray`, or `SparseSpecialArray`, or whatever):

```
template<typename ContainerType, typename ArrayType>
ContainerType extract(const ArrayType& array, ...)
```

Finally, you could create a separate `algorithms` namespace with all the functions which act on `ArrayType` data (e.g, `SpecialArray`). This would make it very straightforward to document and maintain your code: all generic operations for your data type live in `algorithms::`, and a namespace is a much more natural *aggregator* for this kind of operation than, say, a class with many static methods.

Answer (score 2):

```
template < typename OutIt >
void extract(SpecialArray const&, OutIt dest_begin);
```

This works on any container, for any kind of pre-allocation of the container where the result is stored.

If you write the elements successively (à la `push_back`), you can use a `back_insert_iterator` to resize the container if necessary, but this will resize e.g. a vector if not large enough, which results in some performance impact. Otherwise, you might want to use a Random Access Iterator (doesn't change the function template signature, maybe change name from `OutIt` to `RAIt`).

You might want to add a (member) function to get the required size for pre-allocation (member if it has to access private data members).

```
std::size_t extract_size() const;
```

Example:

```
SpecialArray my_special;

constexpr std::size_t len = 100;
int                  dest_ra[len];
std::array<int, len> dest_a;
std::vector<int>     dest_v;
std::list<int>       dest_l;

if( len >= my_special.extract_length() )
{
    extract( my_special, std::begin(dest_ra) );
    extract( my_special, std::begin(dest_a) );
}

// using `push_back`:
  dest_v.reserve( my_special.extract_length() );       // not necessary
  extract( my_special, std::back_inserter(dest_v) );

  extract( my_special, std::back_inserter(dest_l) );

// if random access is required, also a bit faster(*):
  dest_v.resize( my_special.extract_length() );
  extract( my_special, std::begin(dest_v) );

  // not possible for the list
```

(*) `back_insert_iterator` has to do range checks in order to enlarge the vector. If you use an ordinary iterator, there are no range checks.

---

I like Arrieta's argumentation and agree on the judgement of the options.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 4**

Implement public member function for the class SpecialArray:

```
std::vector<int> extract(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally just implement a ToVector(...) method inside the SpecialArray class. If you dont have access to the source code (which I believe you do) you can add the method as extension to that class.

As far as I understand your problem is that you do have a SpecialArray in memory and you want to convert it to std::vector. If both of these classes are isolated in memory (i.e. there is no caching in place to increase the conversion performance) then you only need one method that grabs a SpecialArray and converts it to a std::vector. Doesnt matter if it is a Constructor or a regular method as long as the SpecialArray is passed by reference.